# Why and where do we use array in software development

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, webforms

I am new to programming and everyone discuss about array. I have gone through array in C# and tried it in console. If someone can say me where do we exactly use array in real time software development. I know its a basic question but couldn't figure it out. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to read more about [data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure)

Comment: I wasn't fast enough with my answer... I'll leave it as a comment:

The point of data structures is to come up with different methods of storing collections of the same data so that different operations are more efficient, depending on usage patterns.  This is a common problem to have once you've abstracted a real-world concept into a model - such as a Person into a `Person` class.  Rather than re-writing data structures libraries from scratch each time we reuse them across different types (in C# generics help us accomplish this).

Comment: Arrays and Linked Lists provide the basic building blocks of data structures.

Arrays store the type of object (or references to the same type of object) all in a row in memory.  It has constant (O(1)) access time to find an element, but linear (O(n)) insert time to put an element at the front.

Linked lists are the opposite - you only store a reference to the first item.  It takes in general linear time to find an element, but constant time to put an element at the front.

Comment: When you combine the two concepts together you can get some powerful hybrid data structures - hash sets (I think of them as predominately arrays of linked lists) and trees (I think of them as predominately linked lists of arrays) that find ways to get fast operations all around.

In addition to arbitrary inserts and reads there are other operations to consider, as well.

Comment: You should look into a Data Structures book, course or website to understand all these concepts more fully.  Unless you're going to be implementing the libraries it's probably more important to learn the major data structures and their space and time complexity more so than their implementation so you know when to use them and how it will affect the performance of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically use an array or a list where you have multiple instances of data with the same structure.  Imaging for instance that you want to display a list of all users in your system then behind the scenes you might want to hold them as `User[] users = new User[]` rather than `User user1, User user2, etc...`  It makes it a lot easier to do the same thing to (or with) each element of the list e.g.`foreach(User user in users){...}` than if you had to hold each entry separately.

Comment: Instead we can use sql query to fetch all the users details and display? wat is the difference between writing sql query and using array? As I am beginner I am using array only in console application I dont know how to use this concept in asp web forms.. Sorry If I am wrong at any point

Answer (score 0):

You use arrays wherever you need to maintain lists of anything at all. For example, if I need to display a list of users in an organization, I could hold all in an array of objects.

For more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure